# PHP date insert

Tags: php, date

I have a script what insert a date from the value of a input:

PHP:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="expire" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" value="<?php echo (DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', date("d-m-Y"))->modify('+1 day')->format('d-m-Y')); ?>" />
```

You can also edit the date by a date picker!

[The datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHh7h.png)

But when I insert it to the database with this query:

```
$mysql->query("INSERT INTO code(code, file_match, file_size, expire, ip, can_used) 
VALUES ('".$mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['code'])."',
'".$mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['bestand'])."', 
'".filesize('./Hier_je_files/'.$mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['bestand']))."', 
'".time($mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['expire']))."',
'".$mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['ip_whitelist'])."', 
'".$mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['used'])."')"
```

And then echo it with this:

```
<?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $info['expire']); ?>
```

Output is always the date of to day:

[image: output]

Database:

[image: database]

I dont know why, and how to fix it.

Comment: Read the documentation... [`time()`](http://us.php.net/time) doesn't take any arguments and always returns the current time. You're looking for something like `strtotime($input)` or preferably `DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $input)->getTimestamp()`.

Comment: thats by default date store in database....What;s your exact question??

Comment: Also, think about what will happen if someone posts a `../index.php` in the `$_POST['bestand']` field.

Comment: Mention the type for expire in ur db??? It should be in DATETIME

Comment: Run a debugger and see what the value of `$info['expire']` is. My guess is that it's `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   <?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($info['expire'])); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your insert query inserts in database timestamp(converts date to timestamp).
For that,
Either you insert date as

```
$_POST['expire'] = time($mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['expire']));
$_POST['expire'] = date("d-m-Y H:i:s",$_POST['expire']);
```

Then,

```
$mysql->query("INSERT INTO code(code, file_match, file_size, expire, ip, can_used) VALUES ('".$mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['code'])."', '".$mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['bestand'])."', '".filesize('./Hier_je_files/'.$mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['bestand']))."', '".$_POST['expire']."', '".$mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['ip_whitelist'])."', '".$mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['used'])."');"
```

or

```
<?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($info['expire'])); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `strtotime` function for this, because `time` function will always return current time.

Example usage -

In your case echo the date like this -

```
<?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($info['expire'])); ?>
```